Are you your own enemy?

You don't count as your own ally

The book explicitly states that you are not your own ally, but are you your own enemy? For example, if I activate an Ash Gown while next to an ally, burning my ally in the process, can I use my own Champion's Reaction against myself because I am my own worst enemy?

Why is this important, in game terms? You can call yourself an enemy, if you want. Could you provide a reasonable example of mechanics, which work differently depending on this fact?

Champion's Reaction requires an enemy to deal damage to an ally, and both be within 15 feet.

So you want to strike yourself, using this mechanics? — "If the foe is within reach, make a melee Strike against it". I wouldn't say it's reasonable. If you want to hit yourself for some reason, there are easier ways.

Moreover, the feature says "THE foe". It's the same creature which triggers the feature: "An enemy damages your ally". Do you want to damage an ally, or protect them from damage?

I’m my own worst enemy.

@enkrptor My example included damaging my ally with an Ash Gown.

@Strill you doesn't have to be an enemy for yourself in order to activate Ash Gown and damage an ally. It damages all "creatures that are adjacent to you".

@enkryptor I never said you did. I said you need to be your own enemy to activate Champion's reaction in response to damaging an ally with Ash Gown.

@Strill why do you want to  activate Champion's reaction against yourself? What do you want to achieve? Is this question purely academic?

To stop myself from dealing damage to my ally, of course. What else would I be using it for?

Could you please rephrase the question in order to make it more sensible? Something like "can I use Champion's Reaction to protect my ally from my own damage"

Because that's not the question I want to know the answer to. Being your own enemy has more wide-reaching relevance than just this one case.

No.
While PF2e doesn't explicitly define "enemy" — it's not present at all in the glossary, unlike "ally" — it's clear from all contextual use that it's intended to be along the lines of "characters that are opposed to the player characters." Whether it's spells that target all enemies in an AoE, like Divine Wrath, GM guidance, like enemy motivations, or feats that would behave weirdly if a friendly character could arbitrarily be defined as an enemy, like Boundless Reprisal, it's clear that the game assumes that enemies are enemies in the way you'd expect.
There's no precedent, as far as I know, for a character being considered their own enemy, and the rules implicitly assume that they're not. Even beyond that, past the part of the rule you quoted:

If it isn't clear, the GM decides who counts as an ally or an enemy.

I'd expect the vast majority of GMs would rule, outside of joke or highly niche scenarios, that a character isn't their own enemy to a mechanical extent.
